# Lollipop - multiple Google accounts, setting the default

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, accounts

I have two Google accounts - one personal, one for work. I added the work account last, and it seems to show up as the default for the OS and apps I install. I'd like the personal account, which I added first, to be the default Google account for he device.

Can I change this without having to remove both accounts and add them again in the opposite order?

Edit: to clarify -- while each app will ask which account I want to use, that isn't what I'm asking about. I'm asking if we can change which account the device assumes is primary, and therefor which account it displays first. One would think the first Google account added to the device would be the default, but instead it seems to use the last instead.

Answer (score 5):

All applications that use Android's internal Google Account system should ask you which Google Account they should use on their first run.
This includes games, but excludes websites as they do not use any Android framework.

Comment: If you have already selected a default for an app and you want to use a different one, you can try clearing the data for the app (be careful though as this will actually delete all the data for that app). If you clear the data, and then open the app, it should ask you what the default is.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the play store or any google application to choose between your logged in accounts swipe from left to open options and then touch on the account name of yours. You will then see all the accounts that you are logged in with. Now choose the one you wish to use.

Comment: Correct, they do ask. However, they default first to the wrong account. I'm wondering how to change which account appears first.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove accounts until my preferred one was at the top of the list. I added a couple back and my new default wasn't disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

Well your best choice is to backup the apps using a backup application and then switch account and restore the applications. The apps may ask you to choose account now, and you can choose the right one.

One more idea is to backup all apps and clean the data of the play store and Google play services and open the play store again. Now the play store will ask which account to sync with. You can choose the right account. What I don't know is how this will affect the other apps. They must get removed. So please backup first.

Answer (score 0):

Each google app has a menú to choose the default google account you want to use. However since you added last tour business account, that modified your name in the contacts and therefore also on the account name in the Action Bar (TopMenu). So you might just want to modify your name in thr contacts to your name. I think this is what you are looking for.